# Java exceptions and throw clauses

Tags: java, exception

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3) in its `8.4.8.3` clause mentioned about overriding methods containing `throws` clause, but it's not exactly clear what they were trying to say by this:

> More precisely, suppose that B is a class or interface, and A is a
>   superclass or superinterface of B, and a method declaration m2 in B
>   overrides or hides a method declaration m1 in A. Then:
>
> - If m2 has a throws clause that mentions any checked exception types,
>     then m1 must have a throws clause, or a compile-time error occurs.

What  type of  checked exception `m2` should throw in its `throws` clause?

Comment: The same or a super type. It has to be able to throw the exception declared in the overriding method.

Comment: @BoristheSpider About super types, does it explcicitly specified or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example in code:

```
class B implements A {

  @Override
  void m() throws SomeException {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

What is not allowed:

```
interface A {

  void m(); // This is not allowed
}
```

What is allowed:

```
interface A {

  void m() throws SomeException;
}
```

Or even:

```
interface A {

  void m() throws Exception;
}
```

---

Edit:

The second bullet point from your quote:

> - For every checked exception type listed in the throws clause of m2,
>     that same exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the
>     erasure (§4.6) of the throws clause of m1; otherwise, a compile-time
>     error occurs.

Comment: The quote doesn't say anything about relations between those Exception classes. I mean, fornally we it doesn't have to be a super type.

Answer (score 1):

It says that, if your child class throws checked exception which parent doesnt then it will lead to compile time error.

Consider this:

```
class A {
    public void testMethod() {}
}

class B extends A {
    public void testMethod() throws FilNotFoundException {}
}
```

This will throw a compile time error. Further it says, to resolve this, you may need parent's method to throw FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

> What type of checked exception m2 should throw in its throws clause?

`m2` can only `throws`  all or a subset of the exception classes in the throws clause of the overridden method in the superclass.

**for Example :**

```
class Base                     
{
    void amethod() { }
}

class Derv extends Base
{
    void amethod() throws Exception { } //compile-time error
}
```